# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'rec' referenced before assignment

Tags: python

Estoy aprendiendo Python y tengo el error sobre una variable que dice no estar definida. Me preguntaba como definirla ya que creía que no era necesario

```
def listen(text):
    try:
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            print(text)
            voice = listener.listen(source)#voice escuchara lo que digamos por el microfono
            rec = listener.recognize_google(voice, language='es-ES')
            rec = rec.lower() #rec
           
            if name in rec:
                rec = rec.replace(name, '')
                print('Usted dijo: '+ rec)
    except:
        pass

    return rec
```

Comment: Si el `with` falla, `rec` no resulta inicializado. Agrega `rec = None` antes del `try`. Tienes que estar consciente de que la función puede retornar `None`

Comment: Si tu `try` falla aldetdctar lo que se dijo entonces no existe una variable `rec` por lo que al hacer `return rec` esa variable no existe. Tienes que verificar bien la forma en que haces la detección y si es preferible quita el `try` para saber el error o coloca algo mejor en el `except` ya que por ahora solo genera problema el `pass`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pude solucionarlo, el problema se encontraba en una libreria mal instalada, muchas gracias por su ayuda

Comment: Por favor, agrega más detalles para ampliar tu respuesta, como código que funcione o citas de documentación.

Answer (score -1):

Buenas creo que el return deberias tenerlo después de terminar el with antes del except.

```
def listen(text):
try:
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print(text)
        voice = listener.listen(source)#voice escuchara lo que digamos por el microfono
        rec = listener.recognize_google(voice, language='es-ES')
        rec = rec.lower() #rec
       
        if name in rec:
            rec = rec.replace(name, '')
            print('Usted dijo: '+ rec)
    return rec

except:
    pass
```

Comment: No es un ciclo es una *built in function* la palabra reservada `with` se usa para determinar la configuración local que tendrá el bloque de código lo que sería un *contexto*  (muy diferente a un namespace)

Comment: cierto despues del with